# Using XSLT, how can I count how many of a particular value from an XSL file

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file with different teams and within each team there are different people, each has a different position. I want to count how many Supervisors, Service, Administrators and Cancels each team has.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
    <BO>
        <Team>
          <Usrs>
            <TCode>01</TCode>
            <Per>
              <Code>12</Code>
              <Roll>UsrAdministrator</Roll>
            </Per>
            <Per>
              <Code>13</Code>
              <Roll>UsrService</Roll>
            </Per>
            <Per>
              <Code>14</Code>
              <Roll>UsrTechnician</Roll>
            </Per>
          </Usrs>
        </Team>
        <Team>
          <Usrs>
            <TCode>02</TCode>
            <Per>
              <Code>15</Code>
              <Roll>UsrAdministrator</Roll>
            </Per>
            <Per>
              <Code>16</Code>
              <Roll>UsrAdministrator</Roll>
            </Per>
            <Per>
              <Code>17</Code>
              <Roll>UsrAdministrator</Roll>
            </Per>
            <Per>
              <Code>18</Code>
              <Roll>UsrAdministrator</Roll>
            </Per>
            <Per>
              <Code>19</Code>
              <Roll>UsrSupervisor</Roll>
            </Per>
          </Usrs>
        </Team>
        <Team>
          <Usrs>
            <TCode>03</TCode>
            <Per>
              <Code>20</Code>
              <Roll>UsrAdministrator</Roll>
            </Per>
            <Per>
              <Code>21</Code>
              <Roll>UsrService</Roll>
            </Per>
            <Per>
              <Code>22</Code>
              <Roll>UsrAssistant</Roll>
            </Per>
          </Usrs>
        </Team>
    </BO>
</document>
```

My XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
            xmlns:lookup="lookup" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="lookup exsl">
        <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="xml/plain" />
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
        
        <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        
        <xsl:template match="Team">
          
          <xsl:variable name="subCompletedCount">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Usrs/Per/Roll[matches(. ,'Usr[Sup Serv Admin Can]', 'sm')])" />
          </xsl:variable>
          
          <Teams>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Usrs/TCode"/>
            <Count>
            <xsl:value-of select="$subCompletedCount"/>
            </Count>
          </Teams>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I currently have returns the wrong count. It is catching individual characters, Like it catches Assistant or just 'A' because of Admin in my `matches`

Edit to show expected Result:

```
<document>
   <BO>
      <Teams>
         <TCode>01</TCode>
         <Count>2</Count>
      </Teams>
      <Teams>
         <TCode>02</TCode>
         <Count>5</Count>
      </Teams>
      <Teams>
         <TCode>03</TCode>
         <Count>2</Count>
      </Teams>
   </BO>
</document>
```

Comment: @michael.hor257k I edited to show expected result. Team 03 shows a count of 3 because UsrAssistant has the 'A' and it catches on the A of Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Team">  
    <Teams>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Usrs/TCode"/>
        <Count>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Usrs/Per[matches(Roll, 'Sup|Ser|Adm|Can')])" />
        </Count>
    </Teams>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```